# Nodejs and npm error. modules missing

Tags: node.js, npm

```
module.js:340
throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'vinyl'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/morpheyesh/debugall/web-starter-kit/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/gulp-util/lib/File.js:1:80)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

I have major issues with node.js. I try to run any nodejs application or gulp, i get this error, I try to install every module , I keep getting the same error and it requires a new module. Is there anyway where I can install all the modules?

Plus, I have install nodejs through npm? how to install system wide? Gulp is been installed system wide(global). What is causing this error?

`nodejs -v` gives v0.10.30

`npm -v gives 1.4.21

`gulp` 3.8.7

I am working with the google web starter kit. I installed nodejs using apt-get, then install sass, then installed gulp, then npm. Is there a way where I can remove all these and install all of it system wide?

Comment: Have you tried `npm install` in the project directory?

Comment: I did.When I run gulp, I still get the error.

Comment: what are these modules? how can i install them at once?

Comment: I see quite some modules in node_modules folder. I run gulp, I get a missing module, i install it with npm install <modulename>, i run gulp again, I get a new module. Its basically requires all these modules. How do i install all the basic modules at once?

Comment: I tried installing the node_modules manually as and when it asked me to install. Then now I am stuck with `Error: Cannot find module './lib/http-proxy'
I try to install, it says `NPM ERR! not ok code 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like everything is (was?) FUBAR for a while there.  If you have not yet solved these problems, here's what I would recommend.

First, the official (Debian/Ubuntu) packages are a bit behind latest `node`.  I would recommend uninstalling the packages `nodejs` and `nodejs-legacy` and following the instructions here to get the latest versions (packaged and published by nodesource): https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#usage-instructions

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Now you will have a recent node (0.10.35) but an out-of-date `npm`.  Upgrade your `npm`:

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

Things should now work for you; you should be able to run `npm install` in your project directory and all dependencies will be installed correctly.

One thing to be wary of is that you should **never** run `npm update` or `npm update -g`.  This does not update the current (or all global) packages, as one might think.

Comment: The last one also needs a sudo:
`sudo npm install -g npm@latest`

Answer (score 13):

Try updating your global gulp installation:

```
sudo npm install --global gulp@latest
```

Comment: Updated Node, broke Gulp. Used the above snippet and took a big Gulp. Works 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for install all plugins required by gulp :

```
npm install gulp-jshint gulp-sass gulp-concat gulp-uglify gulp-rename --save-dev
```

Source : http://travismaynard.com/writing/getting-started-with-gulp

Answer (score 0):

For me uninstalling gulp and then reinstalling it worked fine. This is with node v5.0.0

```
sudo npm uninstall -g gulp

npm install -g gulp
```